# Error al personalizar y desacoplar AspNet Identity (Net 5)

Tags: entity-framework-core, identity, .net-5

Tengo una aplicación AspNet MVC Net 5 con AspNet Identity y quiero personalizar el modelo y además separar en capas los objetos de Identity. Para la customización estoy siguiendo [este](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0) documento. Sin embargo al momento de crear la primera migración me tira el siguiente error:

[image: Error al crear la primera migración]

Mi DbContext tiene la siguiente forma:

```
public class PGSIdentityDbContext :
    IdentityDbContext<
        AppUser, AppRole, Guid,
        AppUserClaim, AppUserRole, AppUserLogin,
        AppRoleClaim, AppUserToken>
{
    public PGSIdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<PGSIdentityDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.ConfigureBaseConfig();

        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(Schemas.ASPID);

        modelBuilder.ConfigureQueryFilters();

        modelBuilder.ConfigureEntityConfigAspId();
    }
}
```

No me queda claro qué podría faltar.

Comment: De momento te recomendaría que borres la migración, y la crees nuevamente pero usando una consola (o hacer el init directamente). Me ha pasado de tener errores y que la consola del visual studio me diera un pobre o nula descripción del error (y que cuando genere la migración desde la consola, me diera una excepción con el detalle del error). Ahora no tengo mucho tiempo, pero voy a crear un post dentro de no mucho, con el paso a paso para personalizar identity (agregar campos, cambiar el nombre de las tablas o modificar atributos predefinidos).

Answer (score 1):

Faltaría ver como configuras y consumes `Identity`. Revisa que esta configuración este, y que este usando las tablas que reemplazan a las tablas predeterminadas.

```
            services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<PGSIdentityDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Aclaro que esa es una configuración base, pero de ahí la adaptas a tus necesidades.

De igual manera, aca te adjunto un post con el paso a paso para lograr lo que deseas: [Personalizar identity](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/442819/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-modificar-el-c%C3%B3digo-base-que-me-proporciona-microsoft-aspnetcore-ide/442820#442820)