# ¿Cómo puedo modificar el código base que me proporciona Microsoft AspNetCore Identity EntityFrameworkCore?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, code-first

Tengo implementado [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore) `versión 6.0.0-preview.2.21154.6` con `ASP.Net Core 5` para el manejo de la parte de la seguridad y registros de usuarios de mi aplicación, pero actualmente esta con la configuración predeterminada, y me gustaría poder editarla para ser capaz de agregar mas columnas a las tablas, configurar las columnas predeterminadas y poder cambiar los nombres de las tablas para que sigan las mismas normas que el resto de mis tablas (especialmente eliminar el **AspNet** que tienen todas las tablas). Tengo creada una `Class library` con el nombre `DataAccess` en donde coloque toda la lógica relacionada a la conexión con mi base de datos (en donde uso `IdentityDbContext`), la cual es `SQL Server` y otra `Class library` con el nombre `Domain` en donde tengo las definiciones de mis entidades.

Adjunto el código de mi clase con mi `SecuritiesDbContext`:

```
public class SecuritiesDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public SecuritiesDbContext(DbContextOptions<SecuritiesDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Preparación

---

Antes de la implementación como tal, voy a definir primero la estructura de los archivos y que contiene cada uno en donde despues trabajaremos.
En tu capa `Domain`, Crea una carpeta `Entity` en donde definiremos las entidades personalizadas y dentro de esta, otra carpeta llamada `MicrosoftIdentity`, en donde colocaremos la definición de las entidades propias de la librearía. En tu capa `DataAccess`, crea una carpeta llamada `EF` en donde colocaremos todo lo relacionado a las migraciones y la configuración de Entity Framework. Finalmente dentro de esta carpeta, crea una llamada `EntitiesConfigurations` en donde crearemos las configuraciones personalizadas de las entidades utilizando el `Fluent API` y dentro de esta, otra carpeta llamada `MicrosoftIdentity`. Te debería quedar algo como esto quitando todo las otras cosas que puedas tener en estas capas (para el ejemplo llamare `SecuritiesDbContext` a mi contexto):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Implementación

---

En la carpeta `MicrosoftIdentity` de tu capa `Domain`, crea una clase por cada una de las que te proporciona la librería con el nuevo nombre de cada entidad, y hereda en cada una de estas la clase de `identity` correspondiente, pasándole como parámetro genérico el tipo de dato que desees (`GUID` o `int`), en mi caso usare `int` para todas las entidades. Aquí coloco a modo de ejemplo la entidad `IdentityRole` con mi clase `Role`, y harías lo mismo para el resto (`IdentityRoleClaim`, `IdentityUser`, `IdentityUserClaim`, `IdentityUserLogin`, `IdentityUserRole` e `IdentityUserToken`), en mi caso solo les colocare el nombre que tendrían sin el **AspNet**:

```
public class Role : IdentityRole<int>
{
   // Definiciones de nuevos campos
}
```

---

Luego, ve a tu `DbContext` y define lo siguiente (lo relacionado al `schema` es opcional):

```
public class SecuritiesDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int, UserClaim,
                                   UserRole, UserLogin, RoleClaim, UserToken>
{
    internal const string SecuritesSchemeName = "Securities";

    public SecuritiesDbContext(DbContextOptions<SecuritiesDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(SecuritesSchemaName);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(GetType().Assembly);
    }
}
```

Es de **suma importancia** el orden definido en `IdentityDbContext` ya que es el orden en que se especifica cada clase (el `int` es un parametro que pide para definir el tipo de dato de las llaves de las tablas Role y User, también puede ser del tipo `GUID`). Otro **punto de critico**, es el orden definido en el método OnModelCreating, ya que aplica la regla de "Last wins", por lo que la linea `modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(GetType().Assembly);`, que se encarga de buscar todas las configuraciones del `Fluent API` que encuentre en el `Assembly` debe encontrarse despues del `Base`. La linea definida arriba del `Base`, es basicamente para crearle un esquema personalizado a todas las tablas del `DbContext`, que usa la variable con alcance internal (ya que no nos interesa que sea accesible fuera del `Assembly`) `SecuritesSchemaName`. Si no se especificara el esquema, tomaria por defecto el `dbo`.

---

A continuación, en tu carpeta `MicrosoftIdentity` que esta dentro de la carpeta `EntitiesConfiguration`, crea una clase por cada entidad, en donde definiremos en cada una de estas, el nuevo nombre de las tablas, y las configuraciones de atributos personalizadas a través del `Fluent API`. Utilizare la clase `RoleConfiguration` a modo de ejemplo (observa que uso mi entidad personalizada):

```
public class RoleConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Role>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Role> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(nameof(Role), SecuritiesDbContext.SecuritesSchemaName);
 
        // Otras configuraciones de atributos...
    }
}
```

Con `Totable`, modificas el nombre de la tabla, en donde yo especifique de esa forma el nombre, que es una preferencia mía al momento de referenciar nombres de estas o atributos, así si algo cambia, dará error, facilitando el mantenimiento. El segundo parámetro es el esquema, en donde si tu no utilizas uno personalizado, colocarías el por defecto (`dbo`).

---

En tu package manager console has un `Add-migration` y luego de verificar que todo este correcto un `Update-Database` y eso seria todo. Solo no olvides de consumir tu servicio en la clase startup. Acá dejo uno básico (recuerda que usarías tus nuevas entidades ahora):

```
            services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SecuritiesDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

### Resultado final

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar la generación de tablas que ha dado como resultado por favor?

Comment: Ya esta añadido al final del post. Recuerda marcar el check de la respuesta si soluciono tu problema, así otros usuarios con el mismo, sabrán que es valido lo expuesto en el post.

Comment: En realidad el único que puede marcar el check verde de aceptar la respuesta eres tú mismo, solo que dentro de 12 horas todavía, como es una pregunta auto respondida, hay que esperar 24 horas para ello :D

Comment: Pues, como desarrollador C#, ASP.net, está bien, de tu pregunta lo que más resalta es "poder cambiar los nombres de las tablas", y pues, está logrado :D