# Problema al publicar API en .net 6 con Microsoft Identity en producción

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

Tengo una api en .net 6 que en mi máquina funciona perfectamente.
Dicha api utiliza Entity Framework para acceder a dos bases de datos (una de las cuales es la que genera Microsoft Identity).

El caso es que cuando publico en el IIS de producción dicha api y la llamo, está logando en el Event Viewer estos errores (el usuario con el que se accede a las BD es el mismo que con el que accedo desde mi equipo, por lo que tener, tiene permisos de creación y modificación de las tablas para las migraciones):

**Este:**

> Category: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.CommandEventId: 20102
> Failed executing DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text',
> CommandTimeout='30']SELECT CASE    WHEN EXISTS (        SELECT 1
> FROM [AspNetUsers] AS [a]) THEN CAST(1 AS bit)    ELSE CAST(0 AS
> bit)END

**Este:**

> Category: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.QueryEventId: 10100  An
> exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for
> context type
> 'APIService.Data.UserContext'.Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
> (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'.   at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
> Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)   at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)   at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
> SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
> BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)   at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()   at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()   at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader
> ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean
> isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean
> shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)   at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
> isAsync, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean
> inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
> at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream,
> TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String method)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(Enumerator
> enumerator)   at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.<>c.<MoveNext>b__19_0(DbContext _, Enumerator enumerator)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()ClientConnectionId:afc5a4ff-9588-4b72-b427-1c6e138a2e0eError
> Number:208,State:1,Class:16  Exception:
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object
> name 'AspNetUsers'.   at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
> Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)   at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)   at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
> SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
> BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)   at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()   at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()   at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader
> ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean
> isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean
> shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)   at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
> isAsync, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean
> inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
> at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream,
> TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String method)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(Enumerator
> enumerator)   at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.<>c.<MoveNext>b__19_0(DbContext _, Enumerator enumerator)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()ClientConnectionId:afc5a4ff-9588-4b72-b427-1c6e138a2e0eError
> Number:208,State:1,Class:16

**Y este:**

> Category: APIService.ProgramEventId: 0  An error ocurred during
> database migration  Exception: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
> (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'.   at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
> Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)   at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)   at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
> SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
> BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)   at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()   at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()   at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader
> ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean
> isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean
> shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)   at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
> isAsync, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean
> inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
> at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream,
> TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String method)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(Enumerator
> enumerator)   at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.<>c.<MoveNext>b__19_0(DbContext _, Enumerator enumerator)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetSingle[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Boolean& found)   at lambda_method10(Closure , QueryContext )   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)   at System.Linq.Queryable.Any[TSource](IQueryable`1
> source)   at
> APIService.Data.UserContextSeed.SeedUserAsync(UserManager`1
> userManager) in
> C:\Proyectos\MyService\APIService\Data\UserContextSeed.cs:line
> 14   at APIService.Program.Main(String[] args) in
> C:\Proyectos\MyService\APIService\Program.cs:line
> 35ClientConnectionId:afc5a4ff-9588-4b72-b427-1c6e138a2e0eError
> Number:208,State:1,Class:16

¿Alguna idea de por qué en local funciona y en producción no?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: *"En mi local funciona"*... Un clásico... Anyway, ya investigaste? El primer mensaje dice `Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'`. En PROD existe esa tabla? Revisaste que tus cadenas de conexión están apuntando al servidor correcto? Están las tablas de IdentityServer en tu servidor de producción?

Comment: Si. Las tablas existen. He apuntado a ese servidor SQL desde local y funciona. Tiene un usuario y en local se loga correctamente. La cadena de conexión debería ser la misma. No sé qué puede variar.

Comment: Capaz que implementaste una mala customización de microsoft identity y te genera un error con el nombre de las tablas. Acá dejo un post que hice si es el caso (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/442819/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-modificar-el-c%c3%b3digo-base-que-me-proporciona-microsoft-aspnetcore-ide). De mi parte no tuve ningún error al publicarlo en producción.